How to Share External IDP SSO Tokens from a Tab with Bot Messages in Microsoft Teams?
I'm working on a Microsoft Teams application and currently facing a challenge with token sharing between a Tab and the Bot Framework.
Initially, we implemented authentication using Adaptive Cards, where the authentication process was managed entirely through the Microsoft Bot Framework Token Service. This allowed us to store and retrieve users' tokens conveniently from the Token Store.
However, due to a certification requirement from Microsoft, we were informed that Adaptive Cards for authentication on Tabs are deprecated, and we must switch to an HTML-based approach for the Tab.
I successfully implemented 3rd party IDP SSO for the Tab based on Microsoft's documentation. The issue, however, is that the tokens generated during login on the Tab are not stored in the Bot Framework Token Store.
This creates the following problems:
When sending messages to the Bot, the necessary access_token cannot be retrieved from the Token Store.
There seems to be no straightforward way to attach the token to Bot messages or Teams messages.
My Question:
Is there any way to share the tokens obtained from External IDP SSO on the Tab with the Bot Framework so that they can be used for authentication during Bot interactions?
Alternatively, is there another recommended approach to integrate External IDP SSO tokens with the Bot Framework in this scenario?
Any insights, guidance, or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

You can use localStorage or sessionStorage to store the token and use it in both the tab and the bot.

It would be a solution for tabs, but how can I enforce the Teams itself to retrieve the token from the storage, and send it with each message request?

Tokens in the bot framework token store are intended for server-side use by the app’s bot service only. These tokens should never be exposed to the client, ensuring they cannot be accessed from a tab, dialog, or any other surface rendered using an embedded client app.
To sign in users with an External IDP in their tab, developers must implement the authentication flow documented here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab
The only way to achieve a seamless SSO experience across all of an app’s capabilities is to use Entra ID as the IDP.
